# Single sign on using custom API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, single-sign-on

I want to implement a single sign on feature using my own API. Third party application(web application) will call this API and authenticate the users. For the communication between my API and other applications web request will be used. Below is the solution I provided for this,

I have created a API on my application and do the authentication based on request values. After successful authentication, I create the authentication cookie and add it to the response. 
On the other app I used a `HttpWebRequest` and create `CookieContainer`. Then I get the cookies from response and assign those cookies to `Response`.

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();

            foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Add(new System.Web.HttpCookie(cook.Name, cook.Value)
                {
                    Domain = cook.Domain,
                    Expires = cook.Expires
                });
            }
```

In my test environment this works fine since both authentication API and other app are in same domain. But in customer testing phase this does not work due to domain mismatch.  Because  Authentication API is in different domain.

Is there any way to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is impossible with cookies because they are domain bound and are not sent along with requests to domains. I guess you need see about **other** technology.

I hope [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179236/oauth2-vs-apikey-in-a-server-to-server-communication)  link will be useful

Good Luck

Comment: Can I implement OAuth by customizing only my application.(my API) This is because I do not have the permission to modify other app which make the web request to my app.